# How does suspend/sleep store data in ubuntu 18.04 for a laptop?

Tags: 18.04, suspend

I have a laptop with an ssd for the main drive. I'm curious if anyone knows how ubuntu 18.04 stores data when you suspend/sleep a laptop. Is it writing each time to my ssd or does it keep the data stored in RAM in a lower power state? Given the limited nature of writes for ssd's I would like to avoid data being written every time I suspend the laptop because I do it a lot. Also, is suspend different for each release or is it a standard for all versions and distros? Thank you in advance.